# tomcat set redirect based on request url

Tags: java, .htaccess, tomcat, redirect

I recently got a domain for a site that had none but was already published.

Because I needed to test google custom search features on this site I told google to index it.

Now I want to tell google about the new address using the [change of address tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en), which only works if there is a 301 redirection set on place from the old site to the new one (http://X.Y.Z.T/  -> http://example.com).

I know how to do this on apache web server but I have no idea how to do it on tomcat, and this deployment is just tomcat.

Amy ideas?

(P.S. I have an http://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/ filter set for routing and I think I should be able to set a 301 rule base on the source address, but I would rather go with a tomcat deplyment configuration based solution that doesn't involve touching code inside a java class...)

Answer (score -1):

From [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jsp/send-redirect-in-jsp-page/) - just create a small JSP as index.jsp in the root of the old domain and let the JSP do the forwarding.

As an aside, with some degree of regularity Apache is still in front of Tomcat and you can use it to do the redirection for you

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but please read my question again. An unconditional redirection on a single page is not my intention. I want a conditional redirection (request URL contains ip) to the same URL with the domain instead. I want it to work for any page requested (even those that do not exist) and if possible I want to configure it on tomcat without touching or adding anything to my webapp (in a similar way apache does).